# Hive vs HBase vs Pig for time series data with AWS Elastic MapReduce

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapreduce, hbase, hive, apache-pig

I'm trying to perform statistical analysis on relatively flat time series data with AWS Elastic MapReduce. AWS gives you the option of using Hive, Pig, or HBase for EMR jobs- which one would be best for this type of analysis? I don't think data analysis is gonna be on the terrabyte scale- items in my tables are mostly under 1K. I've also never used any of the three, but learning curve shouldn't be an issue. I'm more concerned with what is going to be more efficient; I'm also handing this project off soon, so something that is relatively to understand for people with noSQL experience would be nice- but I'm mostly looking to make the sensible choice for the data I have. An example query I might make is something like "Find all accounts between last week and today with an event value over 20 for each day".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, none of these. You use MR, Hive, Pig, etc when your data is `big`, really big and you are talking about a dataset which not even of ~TB. And you want your system to be efficient as well. In such a scenario using these tools would be an overkill. So the `sensible` choice for the data you have would be a RDBMS of your choice.

And if it is just for learning purpose then use HDFS+Hive or Pig(Depending on what suits you better).

---

In response to your comment :

If I had such a situation like this, I would use HDFS, to store my flat data, with Hive. The reason why I would go with Hive is that I don't see a lot of transformation kind of things going on here. So, yes, I would go with Hive. And, I don't really see any HBase need as of now. HBase is normally used when you need random real-time access to some part of your data. And if your use case really demands HBase you need to be careful while designing your schema since you are dealing with timeseries data.

But the decision on whether to use Hive or Pig needs some deeper analysis of the kind of operations you are going to perform on your data. You might find these links helpful :
http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/hadoop/pig-hive-yahoo-464.html
http://www.larsgeorge.com/2009/10/hive-vs-pig.html

P.S. : You might wanna have a look at [R project](http://www.r-project.org/).

Comment: Ideally, I'd like the software to scale. The data may be kept indefinitely, and if things go well it may go to a much larger scale. I'm more familiar with noSQL databases (mostly mongo) than relational dbs- in general I don't have a whole lot of db experience however. I also want to use EMR because the rest of the system is hooked into AWS- my data is stored in DynamoDB. If you had to choose regardless of my experience with the thought that the data will eventually scale and you had to use Elastic MapReduce, which of the 3 would you choose?
Thanks for the reply btw-

Comment: Thank you for the details. Please have a look at the edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

**A short summary answer:**

Hive is an easy "first option" for your data analysis, because it will use familiar SQL syntax. Because of this there are many convenient connectors to front end analysis tools: Excel, Tableau, Pentaho, Datameer, SAS, etc.

Pig is used more for ETL (transformation) of data incoming to Hadoop. Your data analysis may require some "transformation" of the data before it is stored in Hive. For example you may choose to strip out headers, apply information from other sources, etc. A good example of how this works is provided with the free [Hortonworks sandbox tutorials](http://hortonworks.com/products/hortonworks-sandbox/).

HBase is more valuable when you're explicitly looking for a NoSQL store on top of hadoop ([example](http://hstack.org/why-were-using-hbase-part-1/)).